# Filter array of objects by object property

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I got array of objects

```
const countryList =  [
    { name: 'Afghanistan', id: 'AF' },
    { name: 'Åland Islands', id: 'AX' },
    { name: 'Albania', id: 'AL' },
    { name: 'Algeria', id: 'DZ' }]
```

I want to filter the array by object "id" and get name

Here is what I have already done and it is working

```
getName = (id) => {
    let name=[]
    for (var i = 0; i < countryList.length ; i++) {
        if (countryList[i].id === id) {
            name.push(countryList[i]);                
        } 
    }
    console.log(name[0].name)
}
```

Is there any better way of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make use of `find` array method:

```js
const countryList =  [
    { name: 'Afghanistan', id: 'AF' },
    { name: 'Åland Islands', id: 'AX' },
    { name: 'Albania', id: 'AL' },
    { name: 'Algeria', id: 'DZ' }];
    
    
getName = (id) => {
  let country = countryList.find(c=>c.id === id);
  return country !== undefined
     ? country.name
     : 'not found';
}

console.log(getName('DZ'));
```

Note here that the `getName` returns now a string and doesn't have any side effects like logging the found value in the console. Also the function now does exactly what it's name says, just gets the name.

For further info regrading this method, please have a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

Comment: Just simply checking `country` will be fine in this case because `undefined` is a falsy value. `return country
     ? country.name
     : 'not found';`

Comment: @MaheerAli You are correct. However for someone that doesn't know what the find returns in case of not an element is found, it is more clear to state that returns undefined rather than null for example.

Answer (score 1):

You could find the name, if `id` is unique and take for unknow items a default object.

```js
const
    getName = id => (countryList.find(o => o.id === id) || {}).name,
    countryList = [{ name: 'Afghanistan', id: 'AF' }, { name: 'Åland Islands', id: 'AX' }, { name: 'Albania', id: 'AL' }, { name: 'Algeria', id: 'DZ' }];

console.log(getName('AL'));
console.log(getName('UK'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to get the object and then return the `name` of that object.

```js
const countryList = [ { name: 'Afghanistan', id: 'AF' }, { name: 'Åland Islands', id: 'AX' }, { name: 'Albania', id: 'AL' }, { name: 'Algeria', id: 'DZ' } ]
const getName = id => (countryList.find(x => x.id === id) || {}).name

console.log(getName('AX'))
console.log(getName('DZ'))
```

Comment: that is what I was looking for. Thanks both of you and hopefully I can mark both answers as correct (in 6 minutes). Unfortunately I can not upvote your answers due to my low points. What a nerdy ridiculous rules :D

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the "name" array.

```js
getName = (id) => {
    for (var i = 0; i < countryList.length ; i++) {
        if (countryList[i].id === id) {
            console.log(name[i].name);
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this works too

```
const countryList =  [
{ name: 'Afghanistan', id: 'AF' },
{ name: 'Åland Islands', id: 'AX' },
{ name: 'Albania', id: 'AL' },
{ name: 'Algeria', id: 'DZ' }];

getName=(id)=>{
    countryList.filter(item=>{item.id===id})
    console.log(countryList[0].name)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do with [array.some](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-array-prototype-function/) for performance reasons, if country id is unique.

```
getCountryName = (countryList, id) => {
    name = null;
    countryList.some((x, idx) => {
        result = false;
        if(x.id === id) {
            name = x.name;
            result = true;
        }
        return result;
    });
    return name;
}
```

Usage is

```
getCountryName(countryList, 'AF')
```

Result is

`'Afghanistan'`